# jQuery - Find Val of Select Box and print to body class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I'm trying to write a small script that prints the value of a select box to the body class.

I'm hoping to have it so that when the value changes it auto swaps the old class for the new class (value) Here is a js fiddle of the script i'm working on for it.

It is changing the class just fine but not finding the initial value of the select box on page load.

Any help would be awesome!

http://jsfiddle.net/BMsP8/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
// On load

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (jQuery("select[name=mySelections] option:selected").val() == 'myvalue') {
        jQuery("#page_template");
    }
});

jQuery('#page_template').change(function () { // on change event
    jQuery('body')
    //.removeClass() // remove the classes on the body
    // or removeClass('class1 class2 ...') in order to not affect others classes
    .addClass(jQuery(this).val()); // set the new class
})
```

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/BMsP8/10/

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your `selector` try this,

```
if (jQuery("#page_template").val() == 'myvalue') {
    alert(jQuery("#page_template").val());
}
```

Also you can use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead of [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) or [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) like,

```
jQuery('#page_template').change(function () { // on change event
    jQuery('body').toggleClass(jQuery(this).val()); // toggle the class
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6V7Nu/)

Answer (score 0):

**set your html**

```
<select id="page_template">
    <option value="Default">Default</option>
    <option value="class1">First Class</option>
    <option value="class2">2nd Class</option>
</select>
```

**in jS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert($("#page_template").val()); 

if ($("#page_template").val() == 'Default') {
       $('body').addClass($("#page_template").val());      
        }


    $('#page_template').change(function () { // on change event
        $('body').removeClass().addClass($(this).val()); // set the new class
    })

});
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/BMsP8/10/)**

Comment: This is working great! Is there a way to only removeClass to the one we are adding and not all classes there were previously there?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#page_template').change(function () { // on change event
    var cls = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery('body').removeAttr("class");
    jQuery('body').addClass(cls); // set the new class
});
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/BMsP8/11/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope this helps

**HTML**

<select id="page_template">
    <option value="myvalue">Default</option>
    <option value="class1">First Class</option>
    <option value="class2">2nd Class</option>
</select>

**JS**

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (jQuery("#page_template option:selected").val() == 'myvalue') {
        jQuery('body').addClass(jQuery("#page_template option:selected").val());
    }
    jQuery('#page_template').change(function () { // on change event
       jQuery('body').removeAttr("class");
       jQuery('body').addClass(jQuery(this).val()); // set the new class
    });
})
```

Comment: you can use toggleClass in order to add/remove the current class, instead of removing all the classes